# Android basic usb interaction

Tags: android, arduino

I am working on a very small project, where I have to send a signal via usb to some kind of micro-controller board.

I am completely new to this, although have enough android experience, so just need answers to few questions for now:

1.) Is it correct that I will need some kind of Arduino kit to get even started ?

2.) Isn't there any way by which I can test this using day to day devices or simulator, rather than purchasing the kit itself ?

Please forgive if the question looks silly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! you can communicate with your Android or any other languages like (C#, Java, Php, Python...) with Arduino or other micro controller by USB.

1. Arduino is very easy to start and you can send signal and perform
   the required task. 
   As you code Android, [check this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hteeNdA7pOo) you get clear idea.
2. Yah! Arduino emulator where you can check or
       test. [check here](http://emulare.sourceforge.net/index.php)

Get to know about Arduino [Here](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/HomePage)

Start with this [program](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink) (Hello World of Arduino)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for answer, is it possible for arduino emulator to connect with my device ?

Comment: @viv Yah...just simulate (send data to COM Port) from your device.

Comment: I searched a lot, but didn't found anything regarding connecting simulator with device...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a signal out of the Android USB port. You will need to communicate with another device via bluetooth or WiFi, and have that device communicate via USB to the microcontroller.

If you want to avoid purchasing anything, you could write a small web service that runs on a computer hooked to your microcontroller. When your android app runs, it would communicate to that web server, which would in turn communicate with the microcontroller.

Then, when you are ready to purchase an intermediary device, if you design your code well, you'd be able to repurpose the code to communicate via that device instead of the web service.

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately I don't have the micro-controller, the one I am developing this app for has it, is it possible to easily interface micro-controller with api, how shall this be performed ??